# Expression on Angular-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-directive

I'm using angular-bootstrap datepicker and I want to put a expression so I can candle multiple objects holding datepicker on one page.

So I have this input text for datepicker-popup.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="event.date" is-open=" '{{event.$id}}' " datepick  er-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"/>
```

And I'm trying to set the "is-open" to my event object id, $scope.event.$id, but using `is-open="event.$id"` angular validates $scope['event.$id'] not $scope.event.$id.

Using `is-open=" '{{event.$id}}' "` is-open will watch for a variable on $scope called '1234im_a_id_something_something' instead for the variable on scope called 1234im_a_id_something_something and now I can handle multiple event objects even the new ones that doesn't have an id yet(because they are on

Someone know how can I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried without the single quotes? is-open="{{event.$id}}"

Comment: Yes, without the single quotes I get an error!